# Different CSS per specific url

Tags: javascript, css, prestashop-1.6

I want to add specific `css` when `url` changes:

example:

```
example.org/43-product.html#/2-size-s/11-color-black/28-modele-coffee
```

When I select attribute on my site, the `url` change like if i select the `white color` that will give me:

```
example.org/43-product.html#/2-size-s/8-color-white/28-modele-coffee
```

i want to put a background , when the color black is selected and an other for the white and for every possible combinations.

I used this function for checking the url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("franky") > -1) {
            alert("your url contains the name franky");
        }
    });
</script>
```

But it works only if I refresh the page, is there a way to make it work so that the url changes without any refresh?

Comment: sure, you can do it :) show us your code so we can help

Comment: thanks which code do u need ?

Comment: Please read up on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing [mcve]s.

Comment: @MrStark: `which code do u need ?` -> _Priceless_ !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save your `style.css` as `style.css.php` and fill the top with e.g:

```
<?php
     header('Content-type: text/css');
     $background_color = htmlentities($_GET['background_color'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?>
/* CSS code goes here */
```

...or something similar. Please note that the code is just provided as an example and not secure (Missing if color is set, color exists...)

Comment: thanks , and if i want to add specific css and not a background ?

Comment: The same process, catch it and require_once('PATH_TO_CSS') the wanted file.